# I have a problem with Wi-Fi drivers in kali Linux Wi-Fi booster(TP Link) (TL-WN823N)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, drivers, make

i have a problem with the wifi driver on kali Linux. I installed the driver and it tells me to compile the source of the driver and after compiling it I should see a name of the chip.ko file stored in the driver directory which, however, I do not see very probably due to the result of the make commands followed by make clean which gives me from as error

The company that is making the WiFi booster that I am trying to use is called tp-link and has arrived with a cd whose contents are mainly for the use of the driver on Windows and Apple machines

could someone please help me?

[image]

these are the commands I entered

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [don't post screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read and, more importantly, anyone trying to help will have to type-copy commands you used in order to reproduce the problem, and the messages will not be found by others googling for the same problem. Instead, edit your post to copy-and-paste the output to your question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've prepared the development environment but you haven't yet downloaded the network driver from TP Link's website at https://www.tp-link.com/uk/support/download/tl-wn823n/#Driver

Unzip the downloaded file. Change to the topmost directory in the resulting tree that contains `mainfile` and continue as from step 2.1.3 in the installation instructions.

Comment: I downloaded the file from the tp link site on a pen but in the instructions it doesn't tell me anything about that file
How should i do?

Comment: Do what I said in my answer. Second paragraph.